# Capture or Take Image from gallery gives null pointer exception in android 5.1?

Tags: android, photo, android-sdcard

I want to capture photo and select image from sdcard but when i am selecting image from sdcard it will crash in 5.1 os in other os it is working fine

```
public String getImagePath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }



// Error Coming in this line
String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
```

Comment: For what use do you want to get a file system path? You better use the uri directly for it.

Comment: If your app crashes you should start finding the reason. It will be a null pointer.

Comment: i am selecting image from gallery any where either directory or sdcard

Comment: Yes i knew that already. You told that before. You better react on the things i said and asked if you want help. And react on Drv.

Answer (score 0):

Try below to fetch path:

```
public String getImagePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
            projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```